# How to rotate a video in the new YouTube Studio?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio

Is it possible to rotate a video in the new YouTube Studio even after Google removed the "Classic Studio" button?

Answer (score 0):

There is however a workaround to rotate a video in the new Youtube Studio (even after the Classic Editor button was removed by Google).
It is a bit tricky and I don't know how long it will work.

Here is the way to do it:

- Open new Youtube Studio and select the video to edit.
- Note down/copy the `video-id` of your video to rotate.
- Create a url with your `video-id` as follows:
  `youtube.com/enhance?v=video-id`
- Open that url in a new tab.
- The old enhance edit window appears (which was part of the classic
  studio)
- However, you will only see a `Trim` button.
- Right click the `trim` button and select `inspect`
- Select the line below the highlighted one in the inspect window.
  It should be something like:

```
<div class="enhance-effect" 
id="enhance-rotate-buttons" hidden="true">
```

- In that line: highlight `hidden="true"` and delete it and hit return.
- Now you will see the rotate left/right buttons again.
- Rotate your video and click `Save` or `Save as new video`.

This may take some time.
Done :-)

Comment: Gone as of Oct 2021.

Comment: all I get when I do this is a page not available screen with the monkey.